# Using Unity IoC in LINQPad

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unity-container

I'm very new to using Unity.

I'm trying to test a segment of code in LINQPad. This code uses a DBContext which relies on Log4Net as a service. I'm trying to write the sample code to use the actual DBContext, but can't get it to construct.

The code I'm trying is below. If there is more information needed, please ask for it before down-voting, since I'm not sure how much you need to see to understand my issue, since I'm still learning Unity.

```
void Main()
{
    RegisterObjects();
    var logger = IoCHelper.Resolve<ILogger>();
    //var _logger = new Clark.Logging.MultiLogger();
    var _logger = logger;
    var _ediContext = new EdiContext();
    var transactionId = 1008;
    var limit = 0;

    var temp = new Type210SubscriberProvider(_ediContext)
        .GetAfterNew(transactionId, limit);
    temp.Dump();

    var temp2 = new Type210SubscriberProvider(_ediContext)
        .GetAfter(transactionId, limit);
    temp2.Dump();
}

public void RegisterObjects()
{
    XmlConfigurator.Configure();

    var multiLogger = new MultiLogger();

    multiLogger.Register(new Log4NetLogger());

    IoCHelper.RegisterInstance<ILogger>(multiLogger);
}
```

If I try just this:

```
void Main()
{
    var _ediContext = new EdiContext();
}
```

The error message I am receiving in LINQPad is:

> Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "Clark.Logging.ILogger", name = "(none)".
>   Exception occurred while: while resolving.
>
> ### Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The current type, Clark.Logging.ILogger, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?
>
> At the time of the exception, the container was:
>
> Resolving Clark.Logging.ILogger,(none)

***UPDATE:***

Here is some more detail from the Global.asax.cs file. I'm not sure how to translate this to LINQPad.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    // GlobalConfiguration.Configuration is an HttpConfiguration object.
    ConfigureContainer(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    ConfigureServices(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

}

private static void ConfigureServices(HttpConfiguration configuration)
{
    configuration.Services.Add(typeof (IExceptionLogger), new UnhandledExceptionLogger(GetLogger()));
    configuration.Services.Replace(typeof (IExceptionHandler), new UnhandledExceptionHandler());
}

private static void ConfigureContainer(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.DependencyResolver = new IoCContainer(IoCHelper.Container);

    new LoggingDependencyInitializer().RegisterObjects();

    IoCHelper.RegisterType<IEdiContext>(new InjectionFactory(unityContainer => new EdiContext()));

    IoCHelper.RegisterType<SubscriberController>();
    IoCHelper.RegisterType<ConsumerInformationController>();
    IoCHelper.RegisterType<TransactionTypeController>();
}

private static ILogger GetLogger()
{
    return IoCHelper.Resolve<ILogger>();
}
```

Here is the IoCHelper class:

```
public static class IoCHelper
{
    private static UnityContainer _container;

    public static UnityContainer Container
    {
        get { return _container ?? (_container = new UnityContainer()); }
    }

    public static T Resolve<T>()
    {
        return Container.Resolve<T>();
    }

    public static void RegisterType<TFrom, TTo>() where TTo : TFrom
    {
        Container.RegisterType<TFrom, TTo>();
    }

    public static void RegisterInstance(Type type, object instance)
    {
        Container.RegisterInstance(type, instance);
    }

    public static void RegisterType<T>()
    {
        Container.RegisterType<T>();
    }

    public static void RegisterInstance<T>(T instance)
    {
        Container.RegisterInstance(instance);
    }

    public static void RegisterType<T>(InjectionFactory injectionFactory)
    {
        Container.RegisterType<T>(injectionFactory);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you try  this in LinqPad?  Are you sure it meets all the enironental requirements, for instance for `XmlConfigurator.Configure(); ` ?

Comment: I really just want to test the code for `temp` and `temp2`. Basically just pass the context to my provider and see the results... but to get the context I need all this IoC stuff. EdiContext requires Logger to be in memory somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

When using an *IOC container*, you need to register your types (e.g. map *interfaces* \ *abstract classes* into their real types). Since when you want the container to resolve an *interface*, it will want to find it's mapping before providing the instance.

BTW, if *Unity* doesn't find a map, it will try to construct the type. In your case it fails since you cannot construct an *interface*.

With *Unity*, you can do it either by configuration using:

```
var section = ConfigurationManager.GetSection(SectionName) as UnityConfigurationSection;
if (section != null)
{
    section.Configure(container);
}
```

Or directly:

```
container.RegisterType<InterfaceType, ConcreteType>();
```

Since I see this code line in your example:

```
IoCHelper.RegisterInstance<ILogger>(multiLogger);
```

You are registering `ILogger` with a specific instance. There must be a problem with your `IoCHelper` implementation. Please add more code and I'll edit my answer with a specific solution.

Comment: I'm trying to copy from existing code. In a WebApi project, where would I put/find that?

Comment: My guess would be the Global.asax file.

Comment: Please add the IoCHelper and the ConfigureContainer implementations.

Comment: Added. I guess what I'm wondering, how can I translate the GlobalConfiguration into something I can use in LINQPad?